# Not certain how exactly to filter this simple FLWOR query in XQuery?

Tags: xml, xquery, flwor

I honestly assumed I would not have many issues with this simple query, but I am supposed to write a query that displays which wards have the most gun-related crimes, but I have been stuck on just 1-2 lines of code and keep getting this error in XBase:

> descendant::ward: node expected as input

I tried using "where" in place of the first "let", since I am limiting the results to "GUN" crimes, but then I get this error:

> Incomplete FLWOR expression: expecting 'return'.

Here is my code:

```
  xquery version "1.0";
declare variable $crimes := doc('dc_crime.xml')//crime;


   Query to display total number of gun crimes by ward

<gunCrimes>{

for $ward in distinct-values(doc('dc_crime.xml'))//ward
let $details := $crimes[ward=$ward] 
let $count := count($details)
order by $count descending

return 
<count ward="{$ward}" crimes="{$count}">{$details}</count>
}</gunCrimes>
```

Sample XML snip:

```
 <crime id="13086252">
      <dateTime>2013-06-23T20:02:00</dateTime>
      <month>6-Jun</month>
      <day>1-Sun</day>
      <offense>ASSAULT W/DANGEROUS WEAPON</offense>
      <method>GUN</method>
      <ward>8</ward>
   </crime>
   <crime id="13086254">
      <dateTime>2013-06-23T20:56:00</dateTime>
      <month>6-Jun</month>
      <day>1-Sun</day>
      <offense>THEFT/OTHER</offense>
      <method>OTHERS</method>
      <ward>2</ward>
   </crime>
   <crime id="13086257">
      <dateTime>2013-06-23T20:52:00</dateTime>
      <month>6-Jun</month>
      <day>1-Sun</day>
      <offense>THEFT/OTHER</offense>
      <method>OTHERS</method>
      <ward>7</ward>
   </crime>
   <crime id="13086268">
      <dateTime>2013-06-23T19:54:00</dateTime>
      <month>6-Jun</month>
      <day>1-Sun</day>
      <offense>ROBBERY</offense>
      <method>GUN</method>
      <ward>8</ward>
   </crime>
   <crime id="13086278">
      <dateTime>2013-06-23T21:50:00</dateTime>
      <month>6-Jun</month>
      <day>1-Sun</day>
      <offense>THEFT F/AUTO</offense>
      <method>OTHERS</method>
      <ward>1</ward>
   </crime>
```

I am still very new at XQuery, but can someone please enlighten me on what I am doing wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you extend your sample enough to be a valid document, so we can actually test/run the query?

Comment: There are also syntactical issues right now, like having a comment started but never closed. This is a failure to satisfy the "correctness" criteria in the meaning of http://sscce.org/, which describes guidelines for building samples demonstrating a problem that others can use to help you.

Comment: ...also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for a similar resource.

Comment: I guess, it is wrong closing bracket position at this part: `distinct-values(doc('dc_crime.xml'))//ward`, which should be written as : `distinct-values(doc('dc_crime.xml')//ward)`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Sorry, I posted a few questions with the exact same XML doc, so I felt bad about keep posting it and wanted to keep it simple. I have extended it. As for the comment, I am sorry but I had to delete my name and the book's name/chapter due to a bad experience in the past (got accused of cheating even though I wrote the code). I edited, thanks.

Comment: @har07: Thank you again, it generated a result doc, but only the top result displays gun-related crimes; the rest are various other medthods.  The 3rd is supposed to have the least and the 7th has the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the `crime` elements to those with child `method` equals `"GUN"` in the predicate expression, for example :

```
.....
for $ward in distinct-values(doc('dc_crime.xml')//ward)
(: notice the added `and method='GUN'` in the predicate :)
let $details := $crimes[ward=$ward and method='GUN'] 
let $count := count($details)
order by $count descending
....
```

or filtering the global variable in the first place :

```
declare variable $crimes := doc('dc_crime.xml')//crime[method='GUN'];
```

Comment: Wow! I had no idea that you could simply filter the global variable like that. However, I suppose it makes sense, because they are for such things. Honestly, the book did not go into much detail with global variables, so I got most of my info from Google and you gentlemen! Thank you so very much, I learned a lot!